# iOS CustomKeyboard's UITextField

Tags: ios, custom-keyboard

I have a question that there is a textview in my custom keyboard, when I edit it, it become first responder, I can use my custom keyboard to edit it, then I remove it and resignFirstResponder, back to host App (not container app, not keyboard's home app), there is also have textview like chat frames, but it's useless when I use my custom keyboard to input char?

I think if I can communicate with host app and make host app become key window or become first responder? How to make it?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no correct way to solve it, i'll try to use label not textview in my custom keyboard, just make label's text equal to char. So that, the host app's chat frames are always first responder.